# RxJS and redux-observable: delay(time) is not applied correctly after mapTo()

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I am trying to dispatch 'SET_MIDDLEWARE_TYPE' action with payload.type = 'observable', wait 5 seconds and then make an API call. Currently, the SET_MIDDLEWARE_TYPE action is not being dispatched. If I remove the delay and the mergeMap, it dispatch that action.

Expected:
FETCH_USER_WITH_OBSERVABLE_REQUEST --> SET_MIDDLEWARE_TYPE (wait 5 seconds) --> FETCH_USER_WITH_OBSERVABLE_SUCCESS

Actual:
FETCH_USER_WITH_OBSERVABLE_REQUEST --> (wait 5 seconds) --> FETCH_USER_WITH_OBSERVABLE_SUCCESS

How can I obtained the expected behavior?

Code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { githubApi } from './api';

const githubEpic = action$ =>
 // Take every request to fetch a user
  action$.ofType('FETCH_USER_WITH_OBSERVABLES_REQUEST')
    .mapTo(({ type: 'SET_MIDDLEWARE_TYPE', payload: { type: 'observable'} }))
    // Delay execution by 5 seconds
    .delay(5000)
    // Make API call
    .mergeMap(action => {
      // Create an observable for the async call
      return Observable.from(githubApi.getUser('sriverag'))
        // Map the response to the SUCCESS action
        .map((result) => {
        return {
          type: 'FETCH_USER_WITH_OBSERVABLES_SUCCESS',
          payload: { result } ,
        };
      });
    });

export default githubEpic;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are abandoning the `SET_MIDDLEWARE_TYPE` action when you perform the `mergeMap`. Notice the parameter that you pass into the `mergeMap` called `action`? That cannot make it any further downstream unless you propagate it.

You will need to prepend it to the outgoing stream. I suggest you do the following instead:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { githubApi } from './api';

const githubEpic = action$ =>
 // Take every request to fetch a user
  action$.ofType('FETCH_USER_WITH_OBSERVABLES_REQUEST')
    .mapTo(({ type: 'SET_MIDDLEWARE_TYPE', payload: { type: 'observable'} }))
    // Delay execution by 5 seconds
    .delay(5000)
    // Make API call
    .mergeMap(action => 
      // Async call
      Observable.from(githubApi.getUser('sriverag'))
        // Map the response to the SUCCESS action
        .map(result => ({
          type: 'FETCH_USER_WITH_OBSERVABLES_SUCCESS',
          payload: { result }
        }))
        // Prepend the original action to your async stream so that it gets 
        // forwarded out of the epic
        .startWith(action)
    );

export default githubEpic;
```

Comment: (deleted my previous comment, which misunderstood. This answer is indeed correct.)

Comment: Thanks paulpdaniels!